# How to access controller method in another controller in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have extended class A in class B and i want to use class A methods in class b.

Comment: In CakePHP it is rather unusual to extend controllers other than AppController. What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: Cake is still OOP, so you can just extend it the way you would extend any other class. I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

To share a method between two controllers, place the function in `AppController`.

To share a group of method related to a single feature, [create a new component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) and use it in both controllers. It's the proper OOP way to do it.

Comment: While I agree about creating a component, I rather disagree about placing the method in the AppController because composition is often the better approach than inheritance.

Comment: @dhofstet: I agree, but without knowing what the OP wants..it may be a simple utility method he's after, in which case a whole component might not be necessary. Also, long time no see, I hope you're doing well ;)